# jquery jtable post extra fields

Tags: jquery, post, field, jquery-jtable

Do anyone know a simple way to attach an exstra field in the JTable build-in actions, post methods?

```
 actions: {
    listAction: '/site/site/load/something',
    createAction: '/site/site/load/something',
    updateAction: '/site/site/load/something', 
    deleteAction: '/site/site/load/something+f(FIELDNAME)=' + $(this).attr("data.record.TABLEFIELD") 
    },
```

Right now it just returns "undefined".. Has anyone succesfuly tryed this?

Comment: `$(this)` what is this here actually?

Comment: well yea, it dosnt make sense.. Bad examble.. But what would make the "jtable.js" insert the current record, <td>, something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use custom function on deleteAction. It's well [documented](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/Actions) also with sample code.